# Make Custom Filter to iterate each field and check condition to return

Tags: python, django

I am making `Custom Filter`.

It should check the each JSONField of model and pick up rows depending on conditions.

These are the code what I want.

How can I solve this??

```
class MyText(models.Model):
    myJson = JSONField()

class MyTextFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    post_date = filters.DateTimeFilter(method="post_date_filter")
    def post_date_filter(self, queryset, name, value): 
        for mt in MyText:
            jsonObj = json.loads(mt.myJson）
            if jsonObj['postdate'] > value:
                #do something here????
        #return something here?????
    class Meta:
        model = MyText
```

---

I tried these two. thanks to @Charnel

```
ls = MyText.objects.annotate(postdate=Cast(F('myJson__postdate'), DateField())).values_list('postdate', flat=True)
print(ls)

ls = MyText.objects.annotate(postdate=Cast(F('data__postdate'), DateField())).values_list('postdate', flat=True)
print(ls)
```

Former one shows

```
<QuerySet [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

later one shows

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'data' into field. Choices are: id,myJson
```

I cheched the myJson, one entry is like this

```
{"postdate": "Wed Mar 18 16:44:34 +0000 2020", "id": 1240318188610437122}
```

I tried some tests below, it shows json correctly,,,
so I need the way to pick up item from json....

```
ls = Mytext.objects.annotate(postdate=Cast('myJson', JSONField())).values_list('postdate', flat=True)
print(ls)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dates most probably are stored as strings in `postdate` key, this may be a solution (not tested):

```
from django.db.models import DateField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

MyText.objects.annotate(postdate=Cast(F('data__postdate'), DateField()).filter(postdate__gt=value)
```

And then iterate through the results and do what you need next.
Anyway even if this will work, on big number of records this will be a bottleneck for performance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I loaded each value `jsonObj = json.loads(mt.myJson）` `jsonObj['postdate']`  .Does this `Cast(F('data__postdate'),` means the same thing???

Comment: Basically yes - it means "the the value of `postdate` key from `data` field and convert it to date object". This is needed (still note I didn't test this) because `__gt` expression in your case needs to compare dates, where `postdate` value is stored as string.

Comment: It shows no error but doesn't show anything. even I change `F('data__postdate') `to `F('data__xxxxdate')`  there is no error.....  how can I debug if it fetch the json object correctly???? and I dont need to put something equal to `json.loads`??

Comment: First check that something was actually annotated with `postdate` date. Run this query manually in debug mode and add annotated field selection to see what's in there: `MyText.objects.annotate(postdate=Cast(F('data__postdate'), DateField()).values_list('postdate', flat=True)`

Comment: Thank you, but still I have problem. I updated the article please help?

Comment: Ah wait, `Wed Mar 18 16:44:34 +0000 2020` far from default date format. Try to apply format on date field `DateField(input_formats=<your_format>))`. You can use [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) to build the correct one. Also, I think it's better for you to denormalize date by settings `postdate` field as a separate DB field, instead of trying to deal with json.

Comment: I see I googled around and found Form DateTimeField have `input_formats` member, but models.DateTimeField not.  I will choose the way to input data separately in database. thank you very much